# How to populate table with multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have multidimensional array which is looks like this after loop

```
array(10) {     
    ["id"]=> string(3) "482" 
    ["firstname"]=> string(3) "Ian" ["lastname"]=> string(8) "Phillips" 
    ["candidate_id"]=> string(3) "482" 
    ["vacancy_id"]=> string(3) "157" 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-09-08 10:12:04" 
    ["rejected"]=> string(1) "N" 
    ["rejected_step"]=> NULL 
    ["rejected_reason"]=> NULL 
    ["rejected_date"]=> NULL 
} 

array(10) {     
    ["id"]=> string(3) "692" 
    ["firstname"]=> string(7) "Gareth " 
    ["lastname"]=> string(7) "Thorne " 
    ["candidate_id"]=> string(3) "692" 
    ["vacancy_id"]=> string(3) "157" 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-10-27 16:05:10" 
    ["rejected"]=> string(1) "N" 
    ["rejected_step"]=> NULL 
    ["rejected_reason"]=> NULL 
    ["rejected_date"]=> NULL 
}
```

That's the code where i'm using to echo

```
    <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">
<?php
        echo '   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                     <thead>
                         <tr> 
                             <th class="text-center">ID</th> 
                             <th class="text-center">Person</th> 
                             <th class="text-center">Client</th> 
                             <th class="text-center">Role</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Qualified</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Type</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Priority</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Contact</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Candidate</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Stage</th>
                             <th class="text-center">£</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Cv Send Date</th>

                         </tr>
                     </thead> 
                 <tbody>';
?>                            


<?php if($all_vacancies != null && count($all_vacancies)): ?>
 <?php 
 foreach ($all_vacancies as  $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<b>".$row['client_name']."</b>";?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['qualified'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['priority'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['contact_name'];?></td>

  <?php if ($row['candidates'] !=null && count($row['candidates'])): ?>
         <?php  foreach ($row['candidates'] as $cand): ?>
        <?php             $candidate_id = $cand['candidate_id'];
                          $this->load->model("vacancies");
                          $test= $this->vacancies->get_cvstate($candidate_id);
            ?>
        <?php   $test1=isset($test) ? $test :'';
                foreach ($test1 as $t): 
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

   <?php if ($t !=null && count($t) && $t['vacancy_id'] ===$row['id'] ): ?>
          <td><?php echo $t['firstname'].  " ".$t['lastname']; ?></td>
          <?php else: ?>
            <td><?php echo " "; ?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if ($t['vacancy_id'] === $row['id']): ?>
              <td><?php echo "Cv Stage"?></td>
              <?php elseif ($t['candidate_id'] === $cand['candidate_id']): ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['stage'];?></td>
            <?php elseif (is_null($t['vacancy_id'])):?>
            <td><?php echo "Send Cv"; ?></td>

        <?php endif; ?>
        ?>        

        <td><?php echo '£'.$row['value'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['cv_date'];?></td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this is how looks after echo `td` in foreach

[image]

look at ID 157 ,  Ian Philips and Greath Thorne should be in 1 `<td>` but its echo 2  times `td` because is in foreach loop, how i can make to echo once with values?

Comment: can you add complete table code??

Comment: check now updated thread

Comment: Note that i just take out the Person Header from code

Comment: how many rows will this return `$this->vacancies->get_cvstate($candidate_id);`

Comment: As per your image, u shud have 12 columns.. But your code has only 10...

Comment: Oh yea i remove CV Send Date and Person from my table, and this function return 2 rows with num_rows()

Comment: i bring them back in code in thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is there from first line only. 
A small mistake in candidates part. It happens when you have more than 1 name(if you have 2, it will echo 2 `<td>`). So take the `<td>` for candidates outside. Take one more variable `$name`. Append the candidate names to it. Once the loop is finished, echo the td

```
<?php
$name = "";  <---- new  var
if ($row['candidates'] != null && count($row['candidates'])):
    foreach ($row['candidates'] as $cand):
        $candidate_id = $cand['candidate_id'];
        $this->load->model("vacancies");
        $test = $this->vacancies->get_cvstate($candidate_id);

        $test1 = isset($test) ? $test : '';
        foreach ($test1 as $t):

        endforeach;
        if ($t != null && count($t) && $t['vacancy_id'] === $row['id']):
             $name .= $t['firstname'] . " " . $t['lastname'] ." , "; 
         ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<td><?= $name ?></td>
```

Comment: Thank you , this works :) Now the same thing need for State, like 1st user Can be on Cv Stage but 2nd User Can be on Interview Stage so i have to display 2 Stages in 1 td

Comment: take out the `td`, and do it as above, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

At first, your code is really hard to read - please use correct indention in the future..

Second, you shouldn't print the td inside the for loop or you will get a new column for each candidate which might be not, what you want..

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">
<?php
        echo '   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                     <thead>
                         <tr> 
                             <th class="text-center">ID</th> 
                             <th class="text-center">Client</th> 
                             <th class="text-center">Role</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Qualified</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Type</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Priority</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Contact</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Candidate</th>
                             <th class="text-center">Stage</th>
                             <th class="text-center">£</th>
                         </tr>
                     </thead> 
                 <tbody>';
?>                            


<?php if($all_vacancies != null && count($all_vacancies)): ?>
 <?php 
 foreach ($all_vacancies as  $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<b>".$row['client_name']."</b>";?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['qualified'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['priority'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['contact_name'];?></td>

  <td>  <!-- NEW -->
  <?php if ($row['candidates'] !=null && count($row['candidates'])): ?>
         <?php $i = 0; ?> <!-- NEW -->
         <?php  foreach ($row['candidates'] as $cand): ?>
        <?php             $candidate_id = $cand['candidate_id'];
                          $this->load->model("vacancies");
                          $test= $this->vacancies->get_cvstate($candidate_id);
            ?>
        <?php   $test1=isset($test) ? $test :'';
                foreach ($test1 as $t): 
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

   <?php if ($t !=null && count($t) && $t['vacancy_id'] ===$row['id'] ): ?>
          <?php if ($i++ > 0) echo "<br />"; ?>  <!-- NEW -->
          <?php echo $t['firstname'].  " ".$t['lastname']; ?> <!-- CHANGED -->
          <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo " "; ?> <!-- CHANGED -->
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
              <?php if ($t['vacancy_id'] === $row['id']): ?>
              <td><?php echo "Cv Stage"?></td>
              <?php elseif ($t['candidate_id'] === $cand['candidate_id']): ?>
                <td><?php echo $row['stage'];?></td>
            <?php elseif (is_null($t['vacancy_id'])):?>
            <td><?php echo "Send Cv"; ?></td>

        <?php endif; ?>
        ?>
        </td> <!-- NEW -->

        <td><?php echo '£'.$row['value'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, I added a counter var `$i` which increments for each relevant candidate and adds a line break (instead of a new column..)

Comment: I have already try this one its not not working and gives me a lot of errors like Undefined variable but they are all defined

Comment: I dont testet your code, but the changes I made, wouldn't result in undefined variable warnings.. maybe you should just add the lines I changed to your code..

Comment: Sorry i forget to remove num_rows() from latest comments, but counter is not slove the problem :(